# Fastest method for mapping an array of Boolean True counts to a Boolean Array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 1D array of Boolean "True" counts that I want to map to a 2D array.

```
#Array of boolean True counts
b = [1,3,2,5]

#want this 2D array:

[1,1,1,1]
[0,1,1,1]
[0,1,0,1]
[0,0,0,1]
[0,0,0,1]
```

The faster the implementation (NumPy/SciPy) the better.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure numpy method, using `np.tri` and advanced indexing:

```
b = np.array([1,3,2,5])
k = b.max()
np.tri(k+1,k,-1,dtype=int)[b].T
# array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

UPDATE:

Two solns that should work better if k >> len(b). `m5` and `m6` in the benchmarks.

Benchmark code borrowed and extended from @Ehsan, 2nd condition. Changes: Added m5,m6. Reduced highest test size from 1000 to 200. Changed output dtype from int to int8.

[image]

Interesting observation; my original solution `m2` performs significantly worse on my (low RAM) computer than on @Ehsan's.

Code (new functions only):

```
#@Paul's solution 2
def m5(b):
  k = b.max()
  n = b.size
  return (np.arange(1,2*n+1,dtype=np.int8)&1).repeat(np.ravel([b,k-b],order="F")).reshape(k,n,order="F")

#@Paul's solution 3
def m6(b):
  k = b.max()
  mytri = np.array([1,0],dtype=np.int8).repeat(k)
  mytri = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(mytri[k:],(k,k+1),
                                          (mytri.strides[0],-mytri.strides[0]))
  return mytri[:,b]
```

Comment: This is a nice swap of rows and transpose, however in order to create temporary array `b.max() + 1` columns are needed instead of `b` which is a huge overload.

Comment: @mathfux For larger ranges of counts one would use something like `stride_tricks`: `mytri = np.repeat(((1,),(0,)),k)` `mytri = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(mytri[k:],(k,k+1),(mytri.strides[0],-mytri.strides[0]))`. This uses only `2k` of actual data.

Comment: This is a nice stride trick, so you can update an answer.

Comment: Nice answer. @mathfux There is an easier way of doing it without allocating that memory for large `b.max()` case. You can check out my post for that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pd.DataFrame([[1]*x for x in [1,3,2,5]]).T.fillna(0).values
```

output:

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Comment: elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

You can create array of zeroes of shape required:

```
arr = np.zeros((np.max(b), len(b)))
```

Then you can create a temporary array `x = np.indices(arr.shape)[0]` which is:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4]])
```

And pad `arr` with ones like so:

```
arr[np.where(x<b)] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy approach without the need to create `tri` in case `b.max()` is large:

```
b = np.array([1,3,2,5])
r, c = b.size, b.max()
a = np.zeros((c,r), dtype=int)
a[np.arange(c)[:,None]<b] = 1
```

output:

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```

---

**Comparison** using `benchit`:

```
#@Ehsan's solution
def m1(b):
  r, c = b.size, b.max()
  a = np.zeros((c,r), dtype=int)
  a[np.arange(c)[:,None]<b] = 1
  return a

#@Paul's solution
def m2(b):
  k = b.max()
  return np.tri(k+1,k,-1,dtype=int)[b].T

#@Binyamin's solution  
def m3(b):
  return pd.DataFrame([[1]*x for x in b]).T.fillna(0).values

#@mathfux's solution
def m4(b):
  arr = np.zeros((np.max(b), len(b)), dtype=int)
  x = np.indices(arr.shape)[0]
  arr[np.where(x<b)] = 1
  return arr
```

For different inputs:

```
in_ = [np.random.randint(100, size=n) for n in [10,100,1000,10000]]
```

[image]

```
in_ = [np.random.randint(n, size=n) for n in [10,100,1000,10000]]
```

[image]

So what you pick depends on your `b.max()` value vs. `b.size`. For larger `b.max()` values (compared to `b.size`), **m1** is faster and for smaller `b.max()` (compared to `b.size`), **m2** seems to be faster.

---

**UPDATE**: Adding a new solution and comparison with @Paul's new solutions:

```
#@Ehsan's solution 2  
def m7(b):
  return np.less.outer(np.arange(b.max()),b)+0
```

Or almost equally:

```
def m8(b):
  return (np.arange(b.max())<b[:,None]).T+0
```

comparison:

```
in_ = [np.random.randint(10, size=n) for n in [10,100,1000]]
```

[image]

```
in_ = [np.random.randint(10000, size=n) for n in [10,100,1000,10000]]
```

[image]

including **m8**:

```
in_ = [np.random.randint(10000, size=n) for n in [10,100,1000]]
```

[image]